# Issue importing custom Python modules in Jupyter notebooks with SparkMagic and AWS Glue endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run ETL scripts in Jupyter notebooks using SparkMagic, which is connected to an AWS Glue endpoint via SSH. I followed the tutorial provided in the AWS Glue documentation (link: **https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-jupyter.html**) and successfully set up the connection. I can run Pyspark without any problems.

However, I'm facing difficulties when trying to import custom Python modules that I created. I have ensured that I uploaded my files to the Glue endpoint and placed them in a file directory that I appended to the Jupyter notebook's search path. When attempting to import the module using the following code:

```
from test.base.text import DataFields
```

It fails to import because the Python interpreter is set to use **`/usr/bin/python3`** by default. Instead, I need to use the **`/usr/bin/gluepython3`** interpreter.

```
sys.executable
```

returns

```
'/usr/bin/python3'
```

I have tried several steps to make it use the correct Python interpreter, including:

1. Configuring sparkmagic to use **`gluepython3`**:

```
%%configure -f
{
    "conf": {
        "spark.pyspark.python": "/usr/bin/gluepython3"
    }
}
```

2. Setting the **`PYSPARK_PYTHON`** environment variable in the notebook:

```
alias python="/usr/bin/gluepython3"
```

3. Modifying the **`.bashrc`** file on the Glue endpoint and creating an alias for Python to point to **`gluepython3`**:

```
alias python="/usr/bin/gluepython3"
```

Despite trying these approaches, I have only been able to successfully import the module when running the code outside of Jupyter notebook using an SSH shell and manually invoking the Python file on the endpoint:

```
/usr/bin/gluepython3 /location/to/file.py
```

Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue and make the custom module import work within Jupyter notebooks using SparkMagic and the AWS Glue endpoint would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [notebook in Glue Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/notebook-getting-started.html) (i.e., interactive session) instead. The Glue doc also [suggest migrating away from dev endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/development-migration-checklist.html).

Next, you can upload the files to S3 and add the Python files via `%extra_py_files` or the wheel file with `%additional_python_modules`.

> Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions-magics.html

To have greater control, use the [local Docker development using Docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-docker-image) method, which provides access via REPL shell and Jupyter Lab.